# How do i include jsp code in tags? See example

Tags: html, jsp, tags, liferay

Like the topic says; How do I include ordinary jsp code in tags? (In my case liferay tags, but it could as well be html-tags)

Example:

```
<liferay-ui:panel id="panel-c4" title="Service Bulletins" collapsible="true"
extended="<% if (noService==false) {
                  out.print("false");
                  }
               %>">
Test panel
</liferay-ui:panel>
```

In the example i just want to insert "false" so the expression looks like the following:

```
<liferay-ui:panel id="panel-c4" title="Service Bulletins" collapsible="true"
extended="false">
Test panel
</liferay-ui:panel>
```

This gives me a jasperException.. I´m used to PHP where this kind of code-includes are daily meat.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<liferay-ui:panel id="panel-c4" title="Service Bulletins" collapsible="true"
    extended="${noService}">
    Test panel
</liferay-ui:panel>
```

`noService` must be set in request e.g.:

java:

```
...

    request.setAttribute("noService", false);

...
```

Comment: Great answer! This solved my problems! (Though i face another one, similar to this ;) Note: This is also possible by using Liferay´s pageContext in JSP by doing pageContext.setAttribute("noService", false);

Answer (score 2):

You can have (I'm using ELs, as they are much cleaner):

1. If variable noService is a boolean:

   ```
   <c:set var="isExtended"><%=noService ? "true" : "false" %></c:set>;

   <liferay-ui:panel id="panel-c4" title="Service Bulletins" collapsible="true"
           extended="${isExtended}">
       Test panel
   </liferay-ui:panel>
   ```
2. If variable noService is a String:

   ```
   <c:set var="isExtended"><%="false".equals(noService) ? "false" : "true" %></c:set>

   <liferay-ui:panel id="panel-c4" title="Service Bulletins" collapsible="true"
           extended="${isExtended}">
       Test panel
   </liferay-ui:panel>
   ```

Comment: Nice! This was ery useful! =)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this.

```
<liferay-ui:panel id="panel-c4" title="Service Bulletins" collapsible="true"
extended="<%=String.valueOf(noService)%>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Bean 
read this: 
http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp/usebean.jsp.html